# How can I store HTML form data to csv file in specific folder?

Tags: javascript, html

I wish to store my csv file in the specific folder by using javascript, anyone have ideas?

I have html form and i wish to store in csv file in specific folder, I have try below code but does not work.

```
<form onSubmit="WriteToFile(this)">
<label>Type your first name:</label>
<input type="text" name="FirstName" id="firstName" size="20">

<label>Type your last name: </abel>
<input type="text" name="LastName" id="lastName" size="20">

<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<script>
function WriteToFile(passForm) {

set fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
set s   = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\Users\\sj\\Desktop\\filename.csv", True);

var firstName = document.getElementById('FirstName');
var lastName  = document.getElementById('lastName');

s.writeline("First Name :" + FirstName);
s.writeline("Last Name :" + lastName);

s.writeline("-----------------------------");
s.Close();
 }
</script>
```

The file totally not able store and not able create. Anyone can share me ideas?

Comment: You've got a mix of VBScript and JavaScript here also btw.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Any (modern) browser will not let you. Giving a website access to the user's file system is a big security breach.

See more info here:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/201208/why-do-browsers-disallow-accessing-files-from-local-file-system-even-if-the-html

Answer (score 0):

With Chrome and some experimental flags, The user can allow access to a Directory when prompted, you can read/write to that folder without prompting again.

You will be given a "fileReference" that you would be able to store in the IndexedDB that you can use for later and even after page reload.

https://github.com/WICG/native-file-system/blob/master/EXPLAINER.md

however it's so experimental that you shouldn't use it yet and nobody have that flag enabled. so stick with something like [fileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) or [StreamSaver](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js) for now...